# Change XYZ tile to Color Rendering to Grayscale

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology, xyz-tiles

I want to change Color rendering of the XYZ tile(namely google satellite). In case of raster image we can easily convert using following code.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
myGrayRenderer = QgsSingleBandGrayRenderer(layer.dataProvider(),1)
layer.setRenderer(myGrayRenderer)
```

But this does not seems  work with XYZ tile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the QgsHueSaturationFilter class:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
huesat = QgsHueSaturationFilter()
huesat.setGrayscaleMode(1)

layer.pipe().set(huesat)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Documentation : [QgsHueSaturationFilter PyQGIS class](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/other/QgsHueSaturationFilter.html)

Comment: Code worked perfectly. Thank You.